# Fatal Error / 404 on all pages after update to 3.8.5

Tags: fatal-error, joomla3.8.5

Hi how can i reverse update from 3.85 to 3.6.5 - front end just displays error 404 and templates seem to be this issue

Comment: Did you try see error log?

Answer (score 0):

Without a backup there is no undoing an upgrade.

Do post the errors you're getting (plus other info) if you need help.